Is there a manga for Dragon Ball Daima?
The Dragon Ball Daima anime series already aired its first episode, however, I havent heard anything of a manga. I believe for some segment of the Dragon Ball universe, the manga started later than the anime. Is this the case? Or is there already a Dragon Ball manga out?

Daima has no manga there is only an anime.
